# Подгрузка блоков контента и страниц целиком

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Сейчас сделана подгрузка через Ajax целых страниц:

```
$(document).on('click', '.link', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    if (link == 'index.html') {
        $('#content').prev('.slider').show();
    }
    else {
        $.ajax({
            type:'post',
            url: link,
            success: function(mes) {
                alert(link);
                $('#content').prev('.slider').hide();
                $('#content').html(mes);
            }
        })
    }
})
```

Но появилась необходимость загружать не только страницы целиком, но и просто некоторые блоки из страниц.

Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Либо сделайте так, чтобы сервер возвращал только определённые данные при определённом запросе, либо (не лучший вариант) из полученных данных выбирайте нужные (с помощью JS) и вставляйте в `#content` только их.

Comment: Использовать Backbonejs, разумнее всего

Answer (score 1):

В функции ответа можно обернуть в jquery и использовать .find 
Выглядит примерно так:

```
$(mes).find('#block').html()
```

Comment: Только лучше не делать приведение в текстовый вид (`.html()`), а сразу вставлять куда надо (`.appendTo($('#content'))` и пр.)